# How to test a custom Meteor method with Velocity + Jasmine

Tags: meteor, jasmine, velocity

I have a Collection 'workouts' as follows:

```
Workouts = new Mongo.Collection('workouts');

Meteor.methods({
  workoutInsert: function () {
    var user = Meteor.user();

    check(user._id, String);

    var workout = {
      completed: false,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      userId: user._id
    };

    var workoutId = Workouts.insert(workout);

    return {
      _id: workoutId
    };
  }
});
```

I am wondering:

1) What would a Velocity + Jasmine test look like for this method? I'm unsure where to start and would really appreciate and example!

2) Is this the best practice to define this method and call it client-side? Or perhaps should I create a Workout class and add call this method from an instance method of that class? Or should I perhaps extend Workouts to be it's own class and add instance methods to that?

Answer (score 3):

In Meteor there is several types of testing: Client Integration, Client Unit, Server Integration and Server Unit.

Integration tests mirror your site and will load in your Meteor methods for you(ie. workoutInsert).

If I were testing this, I might have something such as:

```
//File Location: app/tests/server/integration/workoutsSpec.js
Jasmine.onTest(function () {
    describe('workouts', function () {
       it("should call to Workouts.insert",function(){

       //Make user return truthy _id for testing
       Meteor.user() = function(){return {_id : "1";}}

       //Setup a spy to watch for calls to Workouts.insert
       spyOn("Workouts",insert);

       //Call workoutInsert Meteor Method
       Meteor.call('workoutInsert');

       //Verify if Workouts.insert was called
       expect("Workouts.insert").toHaveBeenCalled();
       });
    });
});
```

Lastly, MeteorJS gives you a lot of freedom as to how you implement things and there's no clear best way to do things that works for every scenario. Although, I'd advise against placing any code that interacts with your database on your client. Anything located in your [client folder is publicly accessible/readable](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) to your users( Do they need to see low level validation details?).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, the best practice is to keep your Meteor methods isolated on the server directory. Meteor uses these reserved directory names to give you control over resources that are served to the client, server, or both. You don't need to have them in the same file or directory as your Mongo collections, as all your collections can be available on both client and server. This is usually considered the best practice, especially if you're using frameworks like angular-meteor which rely on Collection definitions being available on the client, so that filters can be passed to them. You can secure and modify permissions for these Collections on the using `collection.allow()/deny()`

So if you kept all your collections in the `collections/` directory they could be defined like so:

```
Workouts = new Mongo.Collection('workouts');
```

would be the contents of `collections/workouts.js`

Then, in your `server/` directory, on the same level as your `collections/`, you can put all your methods in a file at this level or deeper in the tree, like a `server/methods/` directory. Then you can put your methods in a `workouts.js` in this directory, if you like.

```
Meteor.methods({
  workoutInsert: function () {
    var user = Meteor.user();

    check(user._id, String);

    var workout = {
      completed: false,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      userId: user._id
    };

    var workoutId = Workouts.insert(workout);

    return {
      _id: workoutId
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: "the best practice is to keep your Meteor methods isolated on the server directory" but what about methods stubs and latency compensation?

Comment: @Kyll I haven't had a problem with latency so far with Meteor. If you have vigilant subscription management on the client side (such as stopping subscriptions for out-of-view templates and the like), you can keep your latency down even with massive collections. Methods stubs are something I'm still getting used to, but Meteor's official testing framework Velocity does a decent job of managing your stubs for you and so far, I've had a good experience with it.

Comment: What I meant is that by isolating your methods on the server-side you lose the client's capacity to anticipate changes and update the UI optimistically.

Comment: Meteor.methods are defined on the server specifically to be used on the client using Meteor.call(). It's the bread and butter of any secure Meteor app. 
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods

Comment: Yes, but if they are also defined on the client, then the client optimistically runs database updates. This is the purpose of latency compensation through method stubs...